# Entity Framework connection string overrides database connection string

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I have recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2015. I have a web site created in VS 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express using a Entity Framework. When I open the web site in VS 2015 (and updating through NuGet to EF 6), the web site uses the EF connection string NOT the database connection string. If I create a new Entity Framework model within VS 2015 the same thing happens.

How do I get the web site to connect to the correct connection string?

Comment: You can update the connection string on your web.config or app.config.

Comment: It is highly recommended to put the entity model in a separate assembly so updating it won't ever affect the application's connection string.

Comment: The Entity Framework generates a connection string and I am unclear what I need to change this too. In VS 2010 the connection string works.I do not understand why I need to place in a separate assembly (or how to do that) when in VS 2010 it works fine. What do I have to change in VS 2015 to make the EF work?